# 15 players in groups of 3. In 7 rounds can they all play each other?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Players are split into groups of $3$. If players $a,b,c$ are in a group, then player $a$ has played with $b$ and $c$.

It's quite easy to see how if player $a$ played with $b,c$, then $d,e$, and so on until player $o$, it'd only take $7$ games for them to play with everyone.

I've tried finding a solution but can't seem to get it. I also have limited experience in combinatorics.

I think the solution does not exist because there would be many similar solutions, where say you can swap the matchups for rounds 6, and 7. Like sudoku. But since I haven't had success in finding any solution, I either have a faulty assumption or it doesn't exist.

My main assumption is that the solution will be nice and fit into this board I've made. This specific example is not good as $f,g$ never play together and $l,m$ do twice, but you can see that I've decided to set players 1,2,3 at their own tables, and it makes this easily manipulable 6x12 matrix.

This then breaks down into 3x3 matrixes that follow a pattern of [[a,b,c],[c,a,b],[b,c,a]], which is where my assumption lies, but I feel like it would just work that way and I don't have a reason why.

Aside from trial and error, I have no idea where to go from here.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman's_schoolgirl_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Moreover, this can be done in such a way that each person plays each other person exactly one time. This is equivalent to the existence of a (15,3,1)-design, which is answered in the affirmative by [Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem)